# How to add cache headers to Strapi API endpoint

Tags: strapi

I'd like to understand how to enable caching in Strapi for a specific (or any) API endpoint. At the moment when the browser hits my endpoint in the response headers I don't see any caching related headers. Is there a way to use etags and have a long cache time to allow the JSON response to be cached?

There is one mention of [etags in the docs](https://strapi.io/documentation/3.0.0-alpha.x/guides/requests.html#api-reference) but I'm not sure how to implement. If anyone can provide more detailed information it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least for static files this can be done within Strapi itself. The [middlewares documentation](https://strapi.io/documentation/developer-docs/latest/concepts/middlewares.html#core-middleware-configurations) suggests, that there is already a middleware called `public`, which sets a `Cache-Control` header with its `maxAge` when it serves the files from the `public/` directory.

But if you want to get your uploaded files cached (i.e. files within the `public/uploads/` directory), that’s not enough, because the middleware `strapi-provider-upload-local` (not yet documented) runs first.

A recently [published package](https://github.com/alexkainzinger/strapi-middleware-upload-plugin-cache) solves this issue:

```
npm i strapi-middleware-upload-plugin-cache
```

Simply activate it by adding or modifying the `config/middleware.js` file with the following content:

```js
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  settings: {
    'upload-plugin-cache': {
      enabled: true,
      maxAge: 86400000
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

I suggest you manage this kind of thing outside of Strapi.

With another service. For example, if you host you app on AWS, you can use CloudFront.

Comment: Thanks Jim. I've marked your answer as accepted and it looks like that guide page has been removed from the latest version of the docs.

Comment: cloudfront can not be used to set cache headers on the browser. If the origin (strapi) does not return any cache headers, you can only set how much time the content should be cached on cloudfront, but you can't set the cache headers for the browser